# trying to display 3 - 5 commands

Tags: ansible

I was trying to display a few commands with  .stdout - the gives me the mixed output also with   "item"

with item it gives me:

just the strings:

uname -a

uptime

but not the output of those commands

this is the play-book with commented stuff there that does not work:

```
    - name: To Display === UPTIME and KERNEL Version ===
#    - name: "To Display === {{ item }}"
      command: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - uname -n
        - uptime -p
        - uname -r


#        command: uname -n
#      shell: uptime -p; uname -r; rpm -qa --last kernel
#      register: OUTPUT
#    - debug: msg="{{ OUTPUT.stdout('\n') }}"
#    - debug: msg="{{OUTPUT.stdout}}"
#    - debug: var="{{OUTPUT.stdout}}"
#      shell: "{{item}}"
#      with_items: ['hostname', 'whoami']
#        - uptime -p
#
#        - uname -r
#        - rpm -qa --last kernel
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print a subset of the results of your commands on your terminal without using one or more `-v` flags, you can refactor your playbook to show just the standard output from each of the commands using a JSON query. For example:

```yaml
---
- name: display info
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Display uptime and kernel info
    shell: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - uptime
      - uname -n
      - uname -r
    register: output

  - debug: msg="{{ output.results | json_query('[].stdout[]') }}"
```

This will yield output similar to the following:

```
PLAY [display info] **********************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Display uptime and kernel info] ****************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=uptime)
changed: [localhost] => (item=uname -n)
changed: [localhost] => (item=uname -r)

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "22:48  up 4 days,  3:41, 2 users, load averages: 1.26 1.39 1.42",
        "localhost.local",
        "20.3.0"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you great help.   Michael.